# Fibonacci/Euclid algorithm proof explanation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Can anyone explain to me step by step how the following proof proceeds, specifically the last part:

> For $a$ and $b$, $a > b > 0$, the Euclidean algorithm takes $n$ steps. Then $b > F_n$ so that $b > \phi^{n-1}$, and $n - 1 < \frac{log_{10}b}{log_{10}\phi}$.

How do we reach that last fraction with logarithms?

Proof is on the following [page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LamesTheorem.shtml).

Comment: Take log base $10$ both sides.

Comment: Can you work it out please?

Comment: Do you not know how to take logarithms both sides of an inequality?

Comment: I meant what is the reason one would do that in this specific proof.

Comment: That's how you "reach the last fraction with logarithms" as you asked

Comment: I think you are mistaking which proof it is part of. The Lemma that precedes these lines was proven two lines earlier. The discussion is now wrapping Moll's version of Lamé's Theorem. And you do it, because that is exactly what the theorem says.